# user control is larger than standard c#

Tags: c#, user-controls, size

I needed an improved `TextBox` so I created it by user control, but when I add it to a form it has something like canvas and it covers other my objects on the form. How can I change its size like a text box?

Comment: You are doing it wrong.  Derive your own class from TextBox to improve it, not UserControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dock it into user user control and change the default size of the user control in the user control design view. so that its size matches your standards.